# Magento – Images Not Appearing on Frontend as well as Backend

Tags: magento

my product images are displaying as it should both in admin backend and on frontend of website. When i tried visiting the image path e.g.,http://yourdomain.com/magento/media/images/product1.jpg it returned a 404 Not Found Error for all product images although the images are on the correct location and provided correct path.

I surfed many help sites with many of the suggestions and tried everything but that was not working for me. kindly help me

Comment: are you telling images are not displaying only when we visit throug path....

Comment: Have you checked permissions are correct on images?

Comment: Have you installed any security patch?